# How to setup Kafka Client within Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, apache-kafka

I have followed the google tutorial below and am able to run this on my google app engine no problem.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/building-app/writing-web-service

I only run into problems when I try to incorporate a kafka client in the main.py script. The main script is below and when all reference to kafka is commented out this script runs fine again in the app engine.

Can Kafka be used in an app engine? I have tried using both the internal and external kafka IP addresses on GCP with no luck... When I run "gcloud app deploy" with requirements.txt app.yaml and main.py in the same directory (as per tutorial), or even "python3 main.py" (for testing) the script hangs, there is no error message it just doesn't start the server. Again if Kafka references removed it runs fine. Kafka is running fine in the GCP project - can pub and sub from ssh terminals fine.

I have been able to make this Kafka setup work when run on a Google Compute Engine with the Flask app run directly from the VM - (running directly from the VM not using gcloud terminal). Doing this seems to allow kafka to use the internal IP address and avoids any problems with external IP addresses and cross network difficulties that Kafka doesn't seem to like.

Please help!! (This is my first ever SOF question - so be kind and be very descriptive:) )

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from pykafka import KafkaClient
from pykafka.common import OffsetType

clientKafka = KafkaClient(hosts='10.128.0.3:9092')

app = Flask(__name__)

topick = clientKafka.topics['gps_new']
producer = topick.get_sync_producer()


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return(render_template('index.html'))

@app.route('/topic/gps_new/')
def get_messages():\
    def events():
        for i in 
 clientKafka.topics["gps_new"].get_simple_consumer(auto_offset_reset=OffsetType.LATEST,reset_offset_on_start=True):
            yield 'data:{0}\n\n'.format(i.value.decode())
    return Response(events(), mimetype='text/event-stream')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    # Flask's development server will automatically serve static files in
    # the "static" directory. See:
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files. Once deployed,
    # App Engine itself will serve those files as configured in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Have you tried to check kafka documentation about logging levels? It could be worth setting a deeper logging level (DEBUG) in order to see what is happening.

Comment: In python, the module logging and the instruction logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG) could do the job.